# Issue in implementing mutual information

Tags: matlab, implementation

Mutual Information is defined by the formula

```
I(X;Y) = H(X) - H(X|Y) = H(Y) - H(Y|X)
```

where X,Y are some column vectors.In my case,X is a continuous signal and Y is the discretized signal. size(X)=100 and number of discretizations for Y is say 10 and word length of Y is 5(say).Now,I know that first we have to find the joint probability,then the conditional probability and then I(X,Y).In this light,I have the following implementation issues

1. While calculating the joint probabilities,would they be calculated till the size(x) or till word length of the discrretized signal Y?
2. How to obtain a single numeric value of I and a plot of I
3. How to find the channel capacity

Comment: You might get (better) answers over at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: What do you mean by "Word length"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the last part of your equation: what is `H(Y|X)`? It is the entropy of `Y` assuming we know `X`... but `Y` is just a discretization of `X`! More specifically, if we know `X`, then we precisely know `Y`, and so the entropy of `Y` given `X` is zero. This leaves you with

```
I(X;Y) = H(Y)
```

Do any of your questions still need to be answered with this in mind?

Comment: Thank you for the pointers.(A)If Y reduces in size, that is it is compressed, then would still H(Y|X) be zero?? (B) Further,would channel capacity by I / length(Y) ?? (C)If p_1_1=p_11./p_1 and p_1_2=p_12./p_1 and so on be the conditional probabilities of the occurence of symbols 1,2 then I=constant*(p_1_1.*log(p_1_1/p_1*p_1))+p_1_2.*log(p_1_2/(p_1*p_0))+ and so on. If this be the correct way to find I then it is resulting in a series of numbers.How can I obtain a single numeric value as well as a plot of mutual information?

Comment: (A) As long as there is only one value of `Y` for any value of `X`. 
(B) Depends on your definition. Channel capacity usually refers to a theoretical maximum, which may not be applicable in your case. 
(C) What do you want `I` as a function of?

Comment: I can be a function of the number of bins used for quantization say 2(=number of symbols),I am not sure since I do not understand if I=Shannon entropy in this case or not as mentioned in your answer.

Comment: It should be simple enough to compute `I=H(Y)` for each quantization then, yes? In this case the Shannon entropy of `Y` and the mutual information are the same, as `X` gives you perfect knowledge of `Y`.

Comment: How about channel capacity C since I think C = Mutual info I/quantization bins?OR is it something else?Also,does source entropy mean Shannon entropy(Y)/quantization bins or is it divided by the length of the time series?Thank you once again for the conceptual pointers.Shall be obliged.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what definitions you're using. Channel capacity is normally the maximum amount of information per time you can transmit, which I guess in your case is just `log2(<number of bins possible in Y>)`. I do not know how you define the source-entropy.